# How to extract a specific key from the JSON data in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, json

I have the following JSON and I want to extract the only the location and put it in another JSON or array in the same format as before. I am a newbie, hence, it's a bit confusing for me.

This is what I have:

```
let data = {
    "Person"  : [{"name":"harman","comment_count":255},
                 {"name":"aman","comment_count":66},
                 {"name":"mukesh","comment_count":66}],
    "location": [{"name":"delhi","comment_count":255},
                 {"name":"mumbai","comment_count":66},
                 {"name":"chandigarh","comment_count":66}],
    "org     ": [{"name":"dell","comment_count":255},
                 {"name":"apple","comment_count":66},
                 {"name":"hp","comment_count":66}],
    "teams"  :  [{"name":"Real","comment_count":255},
                 {"name":"Juve","comment_count":66},
                 {"name":"Liverpool","comment_count":66}]        
};
```

This is what I want:

```
data2 = {
   "location": [
        {"name":"delhi","comment_count":255},
        {"name":"mumbai","comment_count":66},
        {"name":"chandigarh","comment_count":66}]       
};
```

Comment: `data2.location = data.location;`

Answer (score 2):

Included a snippet below. Just use `var data2 = data.location;` Good luck

```js
  
  window.onload = function(){
  
      let data = {
                        "Person"  : [{"name":"harman","comment_count":255},
                                    {"name":"aman","comment_count":66},
                                    {"name":"mukesh","comment_count":66}],
                        "location": [{"name":"delhi","comment_count":255},
                                    {"name":"mumbai","comment_count":66},
                                    {"name":"chandigarh","comment_count":66}],
                        "org     ": [{"name":"dell","comment_count":255},
                                     {"name":"apple","comment_count":66},
                                     {"name":"hp","comment_count":66}],
                        "teams"  : [{"name":"Real","comment_count":255},
                                    {"name":"Juve","comment_count":66},
                                    {"name":"Liverpool","comment_count":66}]        
        };
        
       var data2 = data.location;
       console.log("data2:");
       console.log(data2);
  
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

do this.

```
data2 = data.location
```